# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $y=\sqrt{u}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ of $y=\sqrt{u}$, $u=7-x^2$

This is on my homework and I don't know what to do exactly. Steps would be helpful!

Comment: Chain rule. Think $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe I should rewrite √u. I'm really lost....oh okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute or use the chain rule, anyway you get
$$
\begin{eqnarray}{}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac d{dx} \left(7-x^2\right)^{\frac12}&=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So first differentiate the square root and then multiply by the derivative of the inner function

> $\hskip2in\frac d{dx} \left(7-x^2\right)^{\frac12} = \frac12\left(7-x^2\right)^{-\frac12}\left(-2x\right)$

Comment: This makes sense!